# Integral on set $A$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need to calculate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A{(|x|(1-|x|))^{(1/n)}\arctan(ny)\over{1+x^2+y^2}} \,dx\,dy,$$

where

$$A = \left\lbrace w\in \Bbb{R^2}: |w|\le \sin(3\cdot \angle(w,e_1)) \right\rbrace,$$

where $e_1=(0,1)\in \Bbb{R^2}$. I know that I have to use Lebesgue's theorem and I know that

$$\pm\pi\over2(1+x^2+y^2)$$ depending on $\text{sgn}(y)$. But I got problem with understanding set $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use
$$
\angle (w,e_1)=\arccos\frac{w\cdot e_1}{|w|\cdot |e_1|}
$$
and
$$
\sin(3t)=\sin t(4\cos^2t-1)
$$
to get a not too complicated inequality for $w=(x,y)$. Since you are at the level of knowing/learning Lebesgue theory, I believe that you can now handle the inequality in more detail.

Comment: Ok. So I have $(x^2+y^2)^2<|x|(3y^2-x^2)$. Is it ok? It still doesn't look well. And if it is, how do I count my integral?